# Using IF to delete Lines from a String in Python - can't filter all newlines

Tags: python, string, docker, newline

Here is my string:

```
FROM nginx:stable
COPY TestDataGenerator/out /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY MockServer/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# comment




RUN chmod g+rwx /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx
EXPOSE 8080
```

Here is my code to remove newlines (only newlines as separate list elements, i don't care about linebreaks after string in a line) and comments (items containing #):

```
content = '''FROM nginx:stable
COPY TestDataGenerator/out /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY MockServer/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# comment




RUN chmod g+rwx /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx
EXPOSE 8080
'''

list = content.splitlines()
    for item in list:
        if item == '' or item.__contains__('#'):
            list.remove(item)
print(list)
```

Here is the result:

```
['FROM nginx:stable', 'COPY TestDataGenerator/out /usr/share/nginx/html', 'COPY MockServer/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf', '', '', 'RUN chmod g+rwx /var/cache/nginx /var/run /var/log/nginx', 'EXPOSE 8080']
```

Out of 4 separate newlines 2 got removed. How can I remove all 4 newlines and why does it behave this way?

Comment: You are changing the list while still iterating over it. Don't do that.

Comment: `res = [x for x in content.splitlines() if x != '' and not x.startswith('#')]`

Comment: You can also do this using regexp replacement: `re.sub(r'^$', '', content, flagls=re.M)`